# Finding E(X). from the basic

Tags: normal-distribution

The diameters of the marbles manufactured follow a N-distribution with $μ = 9$mm  and $σ = 0.125$mm. A marble is classified as oversize if its diameter is more than $9.16$mm.
The diameters of the marbles are measured one by one. Let $X$ be the random variable representing the no. of measurements when the first oversized marble is found. Find $E(X) .$

I found $\text{pr(a randomly selected marble is oversized)} = 0.1003$ via $N\sim(9, 0.125)$.

All I know is $E(X) = \sum [x \times P(X= x)]$, but how to go from that to the answer of $E(X) = 1/0.1003$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the probability of one marble to be oversize than X is a geometric rv with $E[X]=\frac{1}{p}$

You can easy prove this calculating $\Sigma_x x p(x)$ where

$$P(X=x)=q^{x-1}p$$

$x=1,2,3,...$ and $q=(1-p)$

**Proof:**

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=p\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x q^{x-1}=p\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{d}{d q}q^x=p\frac{d}{d q}\underbrace{\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}q^x}_{=\frac{q}{1-q}}=$$

$$=p\frac{d}{d q}\frac{q}{1-q}=p\frac{1}{(1-q)^2}=\frac{p}{p^2}=\frac{1}{p}$$

**Proof through "the basic"**

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=p+2pq+3pq^2+4pq^3+...=p(1+2q+3q^2+4q^3+...)=pS$$

Thus

$$S=1+2q+3q^2+4q^3+...$$

$$Sq=q+2q^2+3q^3+...$$

Let's subtract member to member:

$$S(1-q)=1+q+q^2+q^3+q^4+...=\frac{1}{1-q}$$

(geometric series)

$$S=\frac{1}{(1-q)^2}=\frac{1}{p^2}$$

Thus

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{p}{p^2}=\frac{1}{p}$$

but I prefer the first proof...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I go through the basics and get a result similar to your last statement.  Let the probability of getting an oversized = p and $p^c = q$
$E(X) = [1P(X = 1)] + [2P(X = 2)] + [3P(X = 3)] + [4P(X = 4)] + …
= 1p + 2(q)p + 3(q^2)p + 4q^3p + …
= p[1 + 2q + 3q^2 + 4q^3 + ….]$

Comment: @Mick : I added the proof in my answer